# Django not taking script name header from nginx

Tags: django, nginx

I am using Django 1.8 by the way.

I am trying to deploy multiple Django app at with same domain/subdomain but different URLs so I am using SCRIPT_NAME header.

My Nginx config:

```
location /myapp/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
    proxy_set_header SCRIPT_NAME /myapp;
}
```

Site is loading with this conf but the request. META['SCRIPT_NAME'] is empty as well as when I hover any links, they are showing without 'myapp' in the URL.

Any help?

Comment: It's possible the value is stored in `request.META['HTTP_SCRIPT_NAME']`

Comment: Sorry, getting error HTTP_SCRIPT_NAME : keyerror

Answer (score 3):

I didn't find the answer to this in all my searching, so here it is:

1. This is only properly implemented in Django 3.1.6, so 1.8 won't work.
2. `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/` is wrong, you need `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000` (without the trailing backslash) in order to keep `/myapp` at the start of the URL path. Django expects its requests to start with the value of the `SCRIPT_NAME` header, and strips it off before your apps see it. Django will return an error for any URL that doesn't start like this.
3. If your `settings.py` defines `STATIC_URL` as an absolute path like `/static/`, Django will not prepend it with your script name. Use a relative path like `static/`.
4. If there are any other proxies in between, make sure they are not dropping the `STATIC_FILES` header. For example, if you have another nginx in between then you need to make sure that your `server` block contains the line `underscores_in_headers on;`.
5. settings like `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` are not prepended (and you cannot use the relative path trick as this does something different), so you can fudge this with a line: `proxy_redirect / /myapp/;`, but then most redirects are prepended, so you also need a line before that: `proxy_redirect /myapp/ /myapp/;`. This technique will not work if `/myapp/myapp` is actually a valid path, of course.
6. If you want to serve the static files statically, remember to include a location block for that.

So your nginx block should look a bit like this:

```
location /myapp/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_set_header SCRIPT_NAME /myapp;
    proxy_redirect /myapp/ /myapp/;
    proxy_redirect / /myapp/;
    location /myapp/static/ {
        root /var/www; # files are deployed to /var/www/myapp/static
    }
}
```

and in `settings.py`:

```
STATIC_URL=`static/`
```

and in `requirements.txt`:

```
Django==3.1.6
```

What a nightmare. Does anybody have any better ideas?

Comment: Tim, Thank you!! I have been looking for this a very long time! Your solution is the only one I found to be working with my Mayan-EDMS (build with Django)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to partially resolve this with some help from the following snippet: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/35/

```
location /myapp {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Script-Name /myapp;
    }
```

Then I created a `wsgi.py` file in the myapp folder with:

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

_application = get_wsgi_application()

def application(environ, start_response):
    script_name = environ.get('HTTP_X_SCRIPT_NAME', '')
    if script_name:
        environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] = script_name
        path_info = environ['PATH_INFO']
        if path_info.startswith(script_name):
            environ['PATH_INFO'] = path_info[len(script_name):]

    scheme = environ.get('HTTP_X_SCHEME', '')
    if scheme:
        environ['wsgi.url_scheme'] = scheme
    return _application(environ, start_response)
```

I also had to switch from using

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

for serving the application to using `uWSGI`. For this I followed the instructions at [Setting up Django and your web server with uWSGI and nginx](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html)
but essentially boiled down to

```
pip install uwsgi
```

and then serving the Django app with

```
uwsgi --http :8000 --module myapp.wsgi
```

EDIT: This currently doesn't work for `static` and `media` assets. See this open ticket: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25598

Comment: So probably the main issue that @user1305989 had is still the same, you can formulate it as "manage.py runserver does not respect SCRIPT_NAME header". As for me it seems like a bug in Django

Answer (score 0):

Well that was another one day journey in trying to get things work. Now with success and not to much efforts. Here is a working example off getting django 3.2 run behind traefik on a subpath and on another port:

docker-compose.yaml

```yaml
app:
    build: YOUR DJANGO APP
    command: gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --log-level=debug --timeout 1000 --workers 1 --threads 4 herre.wsgi
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.appheaders.headers.customrequestheaders.SCRIPT_NAME=/$APP_SUB_PATH"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app.rule=PathPrefix(`/$APP_SUB_PATH`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app.middlewares=appheaders"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app.entrypoints=web"

  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.5"
    container_name: "traefik"
    command:
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
```

settings.py

```py
STATIC_URL = "static" 
LOGIN_URL = "auth_login" # <-- we can specify view names here that can be resolved by resolve_url
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URI = "index" <-- again view name
```

In this configuration there is no need to change the wsgi application. But beware that this does not run with "python manage.py runserver" but only with
a deployment server.

Hope that saves anyone the trouble it cost me !